# Conflicting jQuery - Dynamic menu interferes with jQuery of content loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic

At the moment I am using jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js and dynamicpage.js to load the content dynamically from the index page and therefore keeping the header in one file. However, the jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js is interfering with other jQuery in my content.

The code in the content that is not working is as follows:

```
$(".thumbnails").on("mouseover mouseout", 'img', function () {
    var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('.displayed-image > img').each(function(index, element) {
        var el = $(element),
            visibility = el.attr('alt') === alt ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        el.css('visibility', visibility);
    });
});
```

This code makes hidden images visible when the user hovers over the thumbnails. You can see this working here http://intelligen.info/instagram-randoms.html

However if you navigate to this content using the menu at the top of the index page here http://intelligen.info *Personal > Instagram Randoms* , the code is not working. Can anyone tell me how to make the code work with the menu?

Answer (score 0):

Set  no conflit  in the used jquery

Example:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>


 <script> var jquery_ui_1_10_4_custom = $.noConflict(true); </script>
```

Comment: Sorry... <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>

Comment: thnaks, however this seems to stop all the jQuery from working?

Comment: hummm...maybe the problem on the script. What scripts you are using and what is the Jquery you are using?

Comment: I am using jquery-1.9.1.js, jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js and dynamicpage.js.

Comment: there is this error in firebug; TypeError: f is undefined

Comment: It seems a script error. not a jquery conflit. When you spot the error. When you add the jquery.ba-hashchange or dynamicpage

Comment: if i remove  dynamic page the error goes away but then the menu is no longer there because the link doesn't load the content into the index anymore it simple goes to new page

Comment: I understand...maybe the script has an error. You need to inspect wehre is the error and try to found what is the cause. My guest is you jquery is not the right one for the script (is too old). Try jquery 1.4 - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js